# Setting system environment variable via bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a bash script wich I need to add a system enviroment variable **accessible for all users and it should be permanent**. I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
$EDITOR ~/.profile
export MY_VAR="123"
```

But Im getting the error : `line 2: /root/.profile: Permission denied` even if I execute it as root.

Comment: Why are you working with `/root/.profile`, they exist a `/etc/profile` for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is likely because `EDITOR` is not set - so your command becomes

```
~/.profile
```

which tries to *execute* the `.profile` of the invoking user (clearly `root` in this case).

Even if set `$EDITOR` usually points to an *interactive* text editor - it's not going to magically take the following line and insert it in the file. In any case `/root/.profile` is the *personal* `.profile` file for user `root` - no help if you want to modify the system-wide environment.

To make a system-wide change, you should modify either `/etc/profile` or `/etc/environment`<sup>1</sup> - or (better) create a custom file in the `/etc/profile.d/` directory e.g.

```
echo 'export MY_VAR="123"' >> /etc/profile.d/myvars
```

Your script will of course need to be run as root e.g. using `sudo`

---

[1] note that if you use `/etc/environment`, remove the `export` (variables in this file are just defined as simple `name=value` pairs)

Comment: It worked, but only after I restart the OS, is there a way to update this variable without restarting the machine? Thanks!

Comment: @gog not as far as I know - processes inherit their environment when they're started, I'm not aware of any way to "push" a new value to them